# Largest Number in a list using python

Tags: python, algorithm

As a new programmer, how do I get the largest number from a list of integers and also get the last item in a string? Can someone help out?

Comment: Largest value in a list: `max(mylist)`.  Last item in a string: `mystring[-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Max number from a list:

```
nums = [1,5,8,3,-2,6]
max_num = 0
for num in nums:
    if num > max_num:
        max_num = num
print(max_num)
```

or

```
max(nums)
```

Returns 8

Last item in a string

```
string = 'string'
print(string[-1])
```

Returns 'g'

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: @UkemeJeremiah If my answer helped you, please, click 'vote-up' and select correct answer.